# jquery global variable doesn't get updated in ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- PAGER
var pag = 1;
var loading = false;
var pag1 = <?php echo $k1; ?>;
var pag2 = <?php echo $k2; ?>;
var max_pages_number = <?php echo $max_pages_number; ?>;
jQuery('body').on('click',"#registry_show_more",function(){
    if(pag < max_pages_number && !loading) {
        loading = true;
        jQuery(this).hide();
        jQuery("#spinner").show();
        alert(pag1 + ' ' + pag2); //alert 1
        jQuery.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
              data: {
                action: 'registry_paggination',
                page: pag+1,
                p1: pag1,
                p2: pag2,
                page_size: <?php echo $page_size; ?>,
                category: <?php echo $kategoria; ?>,
                category_slug: '<?php echo $kategoria_slug; ?>',
                filtr: '<?php echo $filtr; ?>',     
                access: <?php echo $access; ?>,
              },
              success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
                pag++;
                jQuery("#spinner").hide();
                if(pag < max_pages_number) {
                  jQuery('#registry_show_more').show();
                }
                if(data) {
                  jQuery("#newpages").append(jQuery("#newpages").html() +data); 
                  FB.XFBML.parse();
                  jQuery('.open-iframe-lightbox').magnificPopup({type:'iframe'});
                  pag1 = parseInt(jQuery("#p1").attr('value'),10);
                  pag2 = parseInt(jQuery("#p2").attr('value'),10);
                  alert(pag1 + ' ' + pag2); //alert 2
                  jQuery("#p1").remove();
                  jQuery("#p2").remove();
                }
                loading = false;
              },
              error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                  jQuery("#spinner").hide();                                        
              }
          });
        }
  });
//-->
</script>
```

Variables `pag, pag1, pag2` update after success function. I know it because i use two alerts to check it. But ajax function send default values.
For example:
initial values:

```
pag = 1;
pag1 = 18;
pag2 = 2;
```

first alert shows:

```
"18 2"
```

ajax sends:

```
 page: 2, 
 p1: 18, 
 p2: 2  
 //skiping the rest of variables
```

second alert shows(just updated):

```
 "35 5"
```

All fine but on the next click:

first alert shows: - ok

```
"35 5"
```

ajax sends: - not ok

```
page: 2, 
p1: 18, 
p2: 2  
//skiping the rest of variables
```

second alert shows(just updated): - ok, because ajax send the same data as before

```
"35 5"
```

I don't know why AJAX function sends every time the same data not new updated values.

I started to think, It seems that the variables in DATA section in AJAX function are not the same as global variables pag,pag1,pag2 or they are constant.

I hope the example is clear enough.

Thanks in advance for your answer

.

.

.

.

Edit: 
I managed to solve the problem. Problem was something else. I've used. Append () is add new data but when i used. Html () all works properly. 
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Is there any other pag1 & pag2 global variable related logic in this page? Global variable should be used carefully and try not to abuse it.

Comment: No there is no other global variables pag1 & pag2.. I try to fix it by changing name of these variables and it still sends the same data every time.